# Unable to display div by clicking button

Tags: javascript, html, css

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        div.abc {
            width: 500px;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: red;
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="ok()">  Helloo </button>
    <div class="abc">
        Your Name <input type="text">
        Your Name <input type="text">
    </div>
    <script>
            function ok(){
               document.getElementsByClassName("abc").style.display="block";
            }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

// In above line of code initially I have hidden the div with class name abc,but on clicking the button I want to show that div but onclicking the button desired div is not coming.

Answer (score 3):

[`document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns multiple elements not just one. You'll have to use something like this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("abc")[0].style.display="block";
```

This statement will only affect the first element with class `abc` because of the `[0]`, if you have multiple elements with that class and you want to show them all, you'll have to iterate through the results of `document.getElementsByClassName("abc")` and modify each element.

Answer (score 1):

The function `getElementsByClassName()` returns an array of elements. To access you element, you have to either iterate over all elements that are returned by the function, or you can access individual items by specifying the desired id:

```
function ok() {
   document.getElementsByClassName('abc')[0].style.display = 'block';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

document.getElementsByClassName("abc").style.display="block";

TO

document.getElementsByClassName("abc")[0].style.display="block";

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByClassName("abc")` will return a HTMLCollection array, and therefor it does not have style property.

you can use `document.querySelector(".abc")` instead.

It will run on almost all browser nowadays

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementsByClassName("abc")
```

returns an array. So you need to access it like one as:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("abc")[0]
```

Edited snippet:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        div.abc {
            width: 500px;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: red;
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="ok()">  Helloo </button>
    <div class="abc">
        Your Name <input type="text">
        Your Name <input type="text">
    </div>
    <script>
            function ok(){
               document.getElementsByClassName("abc")[0].style.display="block";
            }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`getelementbyclassname` would always select every  elements with provided class name  because conceptually Classes are meant to be applied to multiple elements. so to select first element use `[0]` like this `getelementbyclassname[0]`

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        div.abc {
            width: 500px;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: red;
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="ok()">  Helloo </button>
    <div class="abc">
        Your Name <input type="text">
        Your Name <input type="text">
    </div><br>
   
    <script>
            function ok(){
               document.getElementsByClassName("abc")[0].style.display="block";
            }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your project has jquery referenced then you can also use its functions `show()`, `hide()`

Example

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
    $(".abc").hide(1000);
});
});
```

`show()`, `hide()` functions take an optional parameter to animate show or hide of div (like 1000 in my example)

Answer (score 0):

I think You need to use `ID` in your div because of in page multiple class are present but ID use only once.

**See here**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        div#abc {
            width: 500px;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: red;
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="ok()">  Helloo </button>
    <div id="abc">
        Your Name <input type="text">
        Your Name <input type="text">
    </div>
    <script>
            function ok(){
               var x = document.getElementById("abc");
               x.style.display="block";                        
            }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```